# understanding pipe() function

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I'm trying to understand how `pipe()` function works and I have the following program example

```
int main(void)
{
        int     fd[2], nbytes;
        pid_t   childpid;
        char    string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
        char    readbuffer[80];

        pipe(fd);

        if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
        {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }

        if(childpid == 0)
        {
                /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
                close(fd[0]);

                /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
                write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
                close(fd[1]);

                /* Read in a string from the pipe */
                nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
                printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
        }

        return(0);
}
```

My first question is what benefits do we get from closing the file descriptor using `close(fd[0])` and `close(fd[1])` in child and parent processes. Second, we use `write` in child and `read` in parent, but what if parent process reaches `read` before child reaches `write` and tries to read from pipe which has nothing in it ? Thanks!

Comment: Closing: Because it's good practice to close what you don't need. For the second question: These are potentially blocking functions. So reading from an empty pipe will just block the reader process until something gets written into the pipe.

Comment: when indenting, never use tabs.  Because each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.   Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Jour gave you 99% of the answer already, in a very succinct and easy to understand manner:

> Closing: Because it's good practice to close what you don't need. For the second question: These are potentially blocking functions. So reading from an empty pipe will just block the reader process until something gets written into the pipe.

I'll try to elaborate.

**Closing**:

When a process is forked, its open files are duplicated.

Each process has a limit on how many files descriptors it's allowed to have open. As stated in the documentation: each side of the pipe is a single `fd`, meaning a pipe requires two file descriptors and in your example, each process is only using **one**.

By closing the file descriptor you don't use, you're releasing resources that are in limited supply and which you might need further on down the road.

e.g., if you were writing a server, that extra `fd` means you can handle one more client.

Also, although releasing resources on exit is "optional", it's good practice. Resources that weren't properly released should be handled by the OS...

...but the OS was also written by us programmers, and we do make mistakes. So it only makes sense that the one who claimed a resource and knows about it will be kind enough to release the resource.

**Race conditions** (`read` before `write`):

POSIX defines a few behaviors that make `read`, `write` and pipes a good choice for thread and process concurrency synchronization. You can read more about it on [the Rational section for write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html#tag_03_866_08), but here's a quick rundown:

By default, pipes (and sockets) are created in what is known as "blocking mode".
This means that the application will hang until the IO operation is performed.

Also, IO operations are `atomic`, meaning that:

- You will never be reading and writing at the same time. A `read` operation will wait until a `write` operation completes before reading from the pipe (and vice-versa)
- if two threads call `read` in the same time, each will get a *serial* (not parallel) response, reading sequentially from the pipe (or socket) - this make pipes great tools for concurrency handling.

In other words, when your application calls:

```
 read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
```

Your application will wait *forever* for some data to be available and for the `read` operation to complete (which it will once 80 (`sizeof(readbuffer)`) bytes were read, or if the EOF status changed during a read).